# How can I set my own id on each model using Backbones collection parse method?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm fetching data that currently comes back to me with no `id` and is causing issues in my datastore, it looks like the id is actually buried in the JSON so ideally what I would like to do is create an unique id for each model in the collection but I'm not entirely sure how to do this, can anyone help explain how this may be done? I know I need to use the parse method but I'm not sure how I loop through the fetched data or maybe this gets done in the model? I'm not sure what code I need to show you here either.

Comment: When you say create a unique `id` for each model, you mean use the `id` returned from the datastore, right? Here is a similar question [backbone parse nested json](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17392713/722238). Could also take a look at [Collection#parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse). Providing the data-structure would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is a little 'wrong' if you're retrieving data from server. The ideal is the server return these id's for you.

But to do that is something like this:

```
parse:(ObjectReturnedFromServer)->
    id = // Get an ID from somewhere
    @set('Id', ObjectReturnedFromServer)
```

Once again, it makes no sense to me, but will work.